# How can I store a concatenated MYSQL string query into a PHP variable?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When using phpmyadmin I'm able to see a concatenated string that was ran from a query using the concat() method from mysql. However, in actual php code, I don't know how to access the string that was concatenated.

for example, in phpmyadmin, this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT("SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE 1") FROM `account`
```

returns this result:

```
SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE 1
```

And the result is what I would want stored in a php variable.

```
$str = "SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE 1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `fetch()` method, it returns an array containing the row data. Then access the result from there. I recommend assigning an alias to the expression, then you can use an associative array for the row.

```
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT CONCAT("SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE 1") AS str FROM `account`');
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$str = $row['str'];
```